# How to make a .xib show up in a custom class

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I was wondering how to connect my custom class and my .xib. In Interface Builder I have changed the class of the Files Owner to my custom class. I then created an IBOutlet and connected it to the view of the .xib. I then added an instance of my custom class to my UIViewController. My custom class is a subclass of UIView, so I set the background of it to black and can see it appear on top of my UIViewController. What I can't see is my .xib???? Here is my code for my custom class... (FreeThrow is my custom class... FetView is my .xib)

```
@interface FreeThrow : UIView {
IBOutlet UIView *mySquareView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIView *mySquareView;
-(void)createMe;
@end


@implementation FreeThrow
@synthesize mySquareView;
-(void)createMe {
[self addSubview:mySquareView];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // I did this to know my UIViewController is showing this class... which it is     
}
@end
```

Here is my code for what I call from my UIViewController...

```
freeThrowView = [[FreeThrow alloc] init];
[freeThrowView createMe];
freeThrowView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 42, 335, 230);
[self addSubview:freeThrowView];
```

What code do I need to add? What do I need to do? What is the problem? Why is my .xib not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly apple doesn't give us a way to truly link a xib to a view via IB alone. You'll have to do it via instantiation. Here are some past answers to similar questions:

[How do I associate a nib (.xib) file with a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238620/how-do-i-associate-a-nib-xib-file-with-a-uiview)

[Loading .xibs into a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120984/loading-xibs-into-a-uiview)