# Load UIView defined in XIB into UIView

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

following a post presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120984/loading-xibs-into-a-uiview), I tried to load a view defined in a XIB file into a view, currently being displayed. Basically, what I want to do is to replace the middle view (see screenshot below) with a different view when the user clicks on the button.

[image: Layout of my ViewController]

This is the simple view I want to load into the middle view:

[image]

And this is the source code of the ViewController:

ViewController.h
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loadxibButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *middleView;
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"click...");
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewMiddleContent" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *nibView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
self.middleView= nibView;
}
@end
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens, i.e. the new view will not be displayed. Can anybody please help?

Thanks a lot
     Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller has a `view` property which, presumably, has three subviews (left, middle, and right).  Instead of just setting a `middleView` property in your controller, your strategy should be to update the primary view's subviews array (removing the one that's to be replaced and inserting the new one).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more question: see my answer to my question (sorry for not using a comment but I wanted to post some extra code)

Answer (score 2):

Phillip, thanks a lot!

Instead of

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewMiddleContent" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *nibView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
self.middleView= nibView;
}
```

I now use this code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewMiddleContent" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *nibView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

nibView.frame = CGRectMake(261, 0, 532, 748);
[[[self view] viewWithTag:2] removeFromSuperview];
[[self view] addSubview:nibView];
}
```

Is this want you meant, i.e. is this like "best practice"?

Bye
    Christian

Comment: Without checking all the details, yes, that's the idea I had in mind.  I'm not sure about "best practice" because I'm not sure I've ever seen an iOS app with that appearance.  I have done something very similar in a Mac app, with views loaded from their own nibs being substituted for placeholder views.  (The other approach, if things get complex, is to create your own **container** view controller.  See docs on that if you're curious.)

Comment: Thanks, Phillip! I'll have a closer look at how to implement my own container view controllers.

Comment: I created a sample project doing something similar with a custom UIView and .xib file. https://github.com/PaulSolt/CompositeXib

Comment: @itsame69: Next time if you want to add something to your question, just edit the question, don't add new things to the question with the help of an answer.